# Decoding TCP Packet in wireshark

Tags: tcp

There is a small piece of code that is making request to Web server through socket. i am able to see that its a TCP over no SSL through wireshark.
My question is, Is it technically possible to see contents of TCP packets? All communication that is sent from mobile is through TCP (primarily by a C code)

Note: This is not duplicate, I have seen many questions here on SO like decoding or sniffing TCP packets but none help the scenario.

Comment: Of course it is possible to see the content of a TCP packet in Wireshark, that's what this tool is for. If you instead ask about making sense of the content by somehow interpreting it: only if Wireshark has a decoder for this specific application protocol, otherwise one can only see the bytes of the payload.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I believe Wireshark calls it a dissector.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes we can see content and follow TCP stream as well. But I have pcap file in which image was shared over TCP. Is their any tool or something that can help to extract such info, file , meta data etc

Comment: @Badddy: This is is a different question and is off-topic since not security related (the original one is off-topic too). But if for example the image is the HTTP response body or the only data send by the peer in the connection in the image then one can simply export these data from Wireshark. For anything else - it highly depends on the protocol and if Wireshark knows how to dissect it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the image is sent over TCP. I know the export option in wireshark. But my actual question was to get image sent through a mobile (socket program) over TCP..

Comment: @Badddy: I'm confused what you are asking. Your title clearly is about decoding the packet in Wireshark, which I interpret as trying to get to the specific payload you want (i.e. the image). And it does not matter in this case if this is a socket program on a desktop or mobile for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've sent the data over straight TCP with no application layer protocol on top, Wireshark itself won't know how to extract objects from that stream. The data is still there, though.

One approach you might take to quickly extract the data from the TCP connection is to right click a packet in that conversation, then go to Follow -> TCP Stream. In the window that pops up, change "Entire conversation" to just the direction in which the file was sent, then change the "Show data as" dropdown to C arrays. It'll create one char array per TCP packet. You can then write some code to save the bytes to a file, with whatever processing you need to include to remove packet headers or anything else that you added in your original sending program.

Another approach would be to use something like [Scapy](https://scapy.net/) to capture packets (or open a pcap file), filter down to just the packets you're interested in, and extract their contents in a similar manner.

Comment: thanks for you response. Theoratically I am clear that I might need to go this way .. but its just strange that there is no packet recosntruction work done so far for a simple plain TCP pcap file

Comment: @Badddy: The "follow TCP stream" is the packet reconstruction. There is nothing more to reconstruct if this is plain unstructured TCP, i.e. just a byte stream.

Comment: @Badddy Exactly what Steffen said. There's no value in dumping raw packets and assuming they're a particular file format, because the whole point of Wireshark's design is that you have a dissector for each application layer protocol. If you come up with your own application layer protocol you have to do your own reconstruction work, even if that protocol is extremely minimal. Since most (if not all) protocols have some kind of header or control data being sent alongside actual content data, dumping it all into one big continuous binary file isn't very useful.